# I pressed ecs+F3+power accidentally,while having ubuntu 14.04 installed

Tags: 14.04

I'm brought back to the 'chrome os is missing screen"...ctrl+d won't get rid of it nor enter I'm pretty much stuck at this screen even when I restart.

Comment: What chrome os is missing screen?

Comment: It sayz "chrome OS is missing or damaged.Please insert a recovery USB stick"

Comment: right so you installed ubuntu over chrome is? what is the refresh button?

Comment: Yea that's what I did...F3

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/chromium-os-dev/Y6yNCdjVWww) may help you:

Also i pulled this directly from that webpage word for word and the credit goes to the blogger/author of said quote from that article:

> The "Chrome OS is missing or damaged" warning is for users who enter
>   that state accidentally.  Ignore what the screen says and press
>   control-D.  We intentionally obfuscate entering dev mode.
>
> The "missing or damaged" screen only shows up the first
>   time you switch to dev mode.  It sounds like this person has
>   been booting in dev mode for a while, and this is the first
>   time he's had trouble.  It also sounds like the guy gets the
>   screen even after typing ctrl-D.

Assuming the problem persists even after typing ctrl-D, it
means that the image is corrupted.  Given the scenario
describe, I think the most likely explanation is that the
test image built and installed with rootfs verification turned
on.  A second, less likely explanation is that the SSD has gone
bad.
"""

So to me it sounds like you are stuck in dev mode and/or have corrupted both Ubuntu 14.04 and Chrome OS. And more than likely you will have to re-install. I am no expert on Chromebooks so I can only give you my best educated answer.

Since I cannot comment because I do not have enough rep (which is dumb) I would like to also ask if you are installing on a Chromebook or using an Iso image on a pc.

Comment: Amma check out the page

Comment: Its already installed on my chromebook I was just curious because to see and it brought me there @TheUserofknowledge

Comment: I have had a similar problem when I installed Ubuntu 13.04 quite a few months back except it was on a Windows. I kind of just gave up on Windows to switch completely to Ubuntu. I have learned more about computers with Linux (Mostly Ubuntu) in general than I have with a Mac or Windows. If it ends up being both of those O.S. do not properly start anymore, boot a live cd or usb to recover your files or to back them up.

Comment: I'm creating me recovery disk (or whatever) but I don't know the model of my chromebook its a acer C7 tho...does anyone know the. Model of acer C7's or does every one comes with there own specific model number